# How do I get the recordcount returned from a stored procedure within another stored procedure without returning the resultset itself?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a complex and potentially large, or potentially empty query that is currently only exposed in a window :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetComplexResultset @arg1 as nvarchar(10), ..., @argN int , @startwindow INT=0, @windowsize INT=20
AS 

..... (T-SQL bits here)

GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCountComplexResultset @arg1 as NVARCHAR(10), ..., @argN INT
AS 

exec dbo.GetComplexResultset @arg1, ..., @argN, 0, 10000

Select @@Rowcount

GO
```

By design , dbo.GetComplexResultset is built to show a small window of results. I expect ComplexResultset to be complex and to change frequently enough to not want to keep synchronizing two stored procedures.

Calling dbo.GetCountComplexResultset returns both the resultset and the number of rows.

I just want the row count.

Is there a way to clear the returning result ?

Comment: Hard to say without more info on what this procedure actually does - does it produce multiple result sets? does it return a single column or many columns? You could use `insert exec` to prevent returning the result set, or maybe pass an additional parameter to control what it does, but more details would be needed for any more clarity.

Comment: An `OUTPUT` parameter perhaps? To be honest you should probably just keep this as one procedure

Comment: Stu - Why is it 'hard to tell' ? I just want to clear the accumulated resultset. 

Charlieface - I thought of that, but the resultset is still returned. If this is a 'very large' resultset, I don't want to return 10,000 entries

Comment: @SeanMunson because we can't see what your procedure is doing, I have implemented solutions for exactly this requirement but the implementation would depend on the internals.

Comment: If it's one procedure then that can decide based on parameters whether to just return count or the whole set

Comment: So you're saying that there is no way, once a resultset is returned within a stored procedure, to purge it from the output?